# Ejecutar programa java desde otro

Tags: java

Tengo este programa que debo ejecutar desde otro.

```
public class Exercici8_p1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Introduzca texto -> ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String texto = sc.nextLine();
    String[] parts = texto.split("\\*");
    System.out.println(parts[0]);
  }
}
```

Desde este debo ejecutar el anterior

```
public class Exercici8_p1b {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try
    {
        Process process =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Exercici8_p1");
    }
        catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error on exec() method");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: y cuál es el problema?

Comment: @EduenSarceño Pues que desde el segundo programa no ejecuta el primero..

Comment: Quizás esto te ayuda https://picodotdev.github.io/blog-bitix/2016/03/como-ejecutar-un-proceso-del-sistema-con-java/

Comment: @E.Betanzos Nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema con tu código y por lo que no sabes si funciona o no se debe a que no estás imprimiendo nada del proceso que estás corriendo, para ello puedes realizar estas modificaciones:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Exercici8_p1b {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dir");
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            // leer la salida de correr el proceso
            System.out.println("Salida del comando:\n");
            String s;
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }


            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

            // leer errores ak ejecutar el comando
            System.out.println("Salida de errores del proceso (si los hay):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al ejecutar");
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora lo segundo, el uso de `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` es algo obsoleto, para procesar correctamente la entrada y salida tanto de entrada y de errores provenientes del proceso se deben de usar hilos para que funcionen al mismo tiempo, por ello se desarrolló una clase específica para ocultar el procesamiento requerido, la clase `ProcessBuilder`.

Te dejo un ejemplo que te permitirá correr tu primera clase de ejemplo:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Exercici8_p1c1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
            String ss = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
            System.out.println("La ruta desde donde ejecutas tu comando es: " + ss);

            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "Exercici8_p1");
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            builder.inheritIO();
            Process process = builder.start();
            int errCode = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Error al ejecutar el comando? " + (errCode == 0 ? "No" : "Sí"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error de lectoescritura");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.err.println("Problema con los hilos");
        }
    }
}
```

El método `InheritIO` te permite asociar los flujos de entrada y salida a los flujos actuales de tu programa, de manera que podrás escribir y leer al programa de manera interactiva como si lo hubieras corrido directamente.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo cual es la finalidad de tu objetivo pero puedes hacer dos cosas:
1. Crear eso como una clase:

Puedes crear tu Exercici8_p1 como una clase y un crear un metodo normal con lo que tiene en el main, desde el otro programa puedes crear un objeto de tipo Exercici8_p1 y llamar al metodo.

2. Utilizar hilos:

Recuerda que el tipo de programacion que se esta usando es programacion imperativa donde hay un flujo de instrucciones, por lo tanto el llamar otro programa basta con correr un metodo mas, pero si quieres crear otro proceso basta con lanzar un hilo mas.

https://jarroba.com/multitarea-e-hilos-en-java-con-ejemplos-thread-runnable/